# How to add dependency to extended service in angular8

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular8

I want to use `LocalStorageService` in `InterceptedHttp`.

**local-storage.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {DataEncryptionService} from '../../shared/data-encryption/data-encryption.service';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {

  constructor(private dataEncryptionService: DataEncryptionService) {
  }

  public getItem(key: string){
    var encryptedData = localStorage.getItem(key)
    return this.dataEncryptionService.decryptData(encryptedData);
  }
  public setItem(key: string, data: any){
    var encryptedData = this.dataEncryptionService.encryptData(data);
    localStorage.setItem(key,encryptedData);
  }
}
```

**http.interceptor.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class InterceptedHttp extends Http {
    currentUser: any;
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
        this.localStorageService.getItem("currentUser"); //this.localStorageService is undefined
    }
}
```

**http.factory.ts**

```
import { XHRBackend, Http, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { InterceptedHttp } from "./http.interceptor";
import { LocalStorageService } from '../shared/local-storage/local-storage.service';

export function httpFactory(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, localStorageService: LocalStorageService): Http {
    return new InterceptedHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions, localStorageService);
}
```

I have added services in providers, like:

```
providers: [DataEncryptionService, LocalStorageService]
```

How can I use `LocalStorageService` in `InterceptedHttp`?

**Update:**

The error I'm getting when `this.localStorageService.getItem("currentUser");` is executed:

```
Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined
    at new InterceptedHttp (http.interceptor.ts:15)
    at httpFactory (http.factory.ts:6)
    at _callFactory (core.js:30489)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:30428)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30372)
    at _createClass (core.js:30462)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:30425)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30372)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:31577)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30392)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

No errors other than this one.

**Update 2:**

`LocalStorageService` is undefined only in `InterceptedHttp`. `LocalStorageService` object is working fine in other class which is not inherited from any class.

Comment: is there any error you are getting?

Comment: @HimanshuSingh I have added error, please check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed decorator property:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

Comment: Where to add this? and what does this means? please provide complete code.

Comment: ```providedIn: 'root'``` specifies that Angular should provide the service in the root injector.  `providedIn` property, which creates a provider for the service. Try using it in local-storage.service.ts.

Comment: `@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LocalStorageService {

  constructor(private dataEncryptionService: DataEncryptionService) {
  }

  public getItem(key: string){
    var encryptedData = localStorage.getItem(key)
    return this.dataEncryptionService.decryptData(encryptedData);
  }
  public setItem(key: string, data: any){
    var encryptedData = this.dataEncryptionService.encryptData(data);
    localStorage.setItem(key,encryptedData);
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})
export class YourServiceName {
}
```

Refer from this site: https://angular.io/guide/providers

Answer (score 0):

While adding http provider in `app.module.ts` I have to added `LocalStorageService` in dependencies:

```
providers: [
{
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: httpFactory,
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, LocalStorageService],
    },
    ...
}
```

Adding `LocalStorageService` in `deps` fixed the issue.